# Visualizing LFW Dataset with PCA: Plotting Face Images Instead of Points for Enhanced Pattern Analysis

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I'm performing a PCA in the LFW dataset, now I want to plot the PCA scores of the first two components but instead of plotting just points I want to plot the faces images to analyze and visualize patterns (if there are).

This is my code:

```
for name in lfw_people.target_names:
    print(name)

n_samples, h, w = lfw_people.images.shape

X = lfw_people.data 

print(X.shape[0])
print(X.shape[1])

n_features = X.shape[1]

y = lfw_people.target 
target_names = lfw_people.target_names
n_classes = target_names.shape[0]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, names_train, names_test = train_test_split(X, y, target_names[y], train_size = 0.80, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 42) 

no_components = 20 

pca = PCA(n_components = no_components, svd_solver = 'randomized', whiten = True).fit(X_train) 

eigenfaces = pca.components_.reshape((no_components, h, w)) 

explained_variance = pca.explained_variance_ratio_ 

X_train_pca = pca.transform(X_train) 

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
for i in range(len(target_names)):
    plt.scatter(X_train_pca[y_train == i, 0], X_train_pca[y_train == i, 1], label=target_names[i])

plt.title('Principal Component Analysis LFW Dataset')
plt.xlabel('Principal Component 1')
plt.ylabel('Principal Component 2')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```